# How to use node's transform stream in rxjs?

Tags: node.js, stream, rxjs

I've been playing with `rxjs` for some time now and I like how I can use it's operators for logic rather than imperative programming.
However, I also like node's stream which are also highly composable so my obvious reaction was to use them both but I haven't seen it being mentioned a lot (actually, I haven't at all) besides the binding for it in rxjs's [book](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/rxjs_bindings/node/index.html).

So, my question really is, how do I make use of all the transform streams that are in npm on RxJS? Or, is it even possible?
Example:-

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv-parse')({delimiter:';'});
var src = fs.createReadStream('./myFile.csv');
src.pipe(csv).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Essentially, I would want to do this:-

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv-parse')({delimiter:';'});
var rx= require('rx-node');
var src = fs.createReadStream('./myFile.csv');

var obj = rx.fromReadableStream(src);
obj.pipe(csb).map(x=>console.log(x));
```

I've been told to use `highland` in the past but I'm strictly looking for `rxjs` solution here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use `rx-node` but you can! Remember: `All streams are event emitters!`.

Prepare:
`input.txt`

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Run:

```
npm install through2 split2 rx rx-node
```

And in the `index.js`:

```
var Rx = require('rx');
Rx.Node = require('rx-node');
var fs = require('fs');
var th2 = require('through2');
var split2 = require('split2');

var file = fs.createReadStream('./input.txt').on('error', console.log.bind(console, 'fs err'));

var transform = th2(function(ch, en, cb) {
  cb(null, ch.toString());
}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err, err.toString());
});

// All streams are event emitters ! (one way without using rx-node)
// var subs = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(transform, 'data').share();
// subs
//   .map(value => 'Begin line: ' + value)
//   .subscribe(value => console.log(value));

// rx-node has convenience functions (another way)
var subs = Rx.Node.fromTransformStream(transform).share()
  .map(value => 'Begin line: ' + value)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));

file.pipe(split2()).pipe(transform);
```

Output:

```
Begin line: Hello World!
Begin line: Hello World!
Begin line: Hello World!
Begin line: Hello World!
Begin line: Hello World!
```

Comment: I did knew that everything is a `stream` but I was being dropped to node's stream when I did `Rx.Observable.fromEvent(transform, 'data')` which stripped me out of `map`, `filter` and other operators that `Observables` have. But I see that you're using `.share()` which I'm assuming converts `streams` to `Observables`? Also, my other attempt was to do `var obs = Rx.fromStream(file.pipe(transform))` which sort of worked. But I'm not sure if that's the standard or brute forcing way of doing thing.

Comment: It works for me without ```.share()```. I'm not experienced with ```rx``` but I think both ```fromEvent``` and ```fromTransformStream``` create ```Observable``` which can be used in ```rx``` system. Second part of question, take a look at ```rx-node``` it has multiple ```from*Stream``` functions so you need to choose right one (write, read stream, transfor...).

Comment: Ahh, I misspoke there. Previously, I was just feeding the `readable` stream and `piping` on it hoping to get `observable`. You're right. Feeding the `transform` stream to `rx` does give `observable`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

EdinM gave a great general example of using RxJS with a node transform stream, but your original question remains unanswered. Since I had nearly the same question a few days ago, I wanted to make an effort at answering it for anyone who isn't familiar with using RxJS with Node. Instead of using the `csv-parse` module, I'm going with `csv-streamify`. Let's set up the basic structure:

test_data.csv:

```
thing,name,owner,loc
chair,sitty,billy,san fran
table,setty,bryan,new oak
```

Run:

```
$ npm install rx rx-node csv-streamify
```

index.js:

```
"use strict";

const Rx = require('rx');
Rx.Node = require('rx-node');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-streamify');


//Setting up the transform-stream CSV parser

let config = {
  delimiter: ',',       // comma, semicolon, whatever
  newline: '\n',        // newline character (use \r\n for CRLF files)
  quote: '"',           // what's considered a quote
  empty: '',            // empty fields are replaced by this
  //objectMode: true,   //parses csv table into an array of objects
  //columns: true       //uses column headers for the object fields
};

let parseCsv = csv(config);

//Setting up the RxJS Observer

function onNext (x) {
    //do your side-effects here, after the data has 
    //gone through the observables operator chain
    console.log('Next: ' + x); 
};
function onError (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
};
function onComplete () {
    console.log('Completed');
};

let readStream = fs.createReadStream('test_files/test_data.csv');

readStream.pipe(parseCsv);

let subscription = Rx.Node.fromTransformStream(parseCsv)
    //do something with the data with an operator such as:
    //.map()
    .subscribe(onNext, onError, onComplete);
```

Now let's run the code:

```
$ node index.js
```

And we'll get this output:

```
Next: ["thing","name","owner","loc\r"]

Next: ["chair","sitty","billy","san fran\r"]

Next: ["table","setty","bryan","new oak"]

Completed
```

### Epilogue

If you set `objectMode` and `columns` to true in the csv config object, and then project this `sideEffect` function with the map operator like so:

```
function sideEffect (v){ 
  console.log(v) 
  return v;
};

let subscription = Rx.Node.fromTransformStream(parseCsv)
  .map(sideEffect)
  .subscribe(onNext, onError, onComplete);
```

You'll get this output:

```
{ thing: 'chair',
  name: 'sitty',
  owner: 'billy',
  'loc\r': 'san fran\r' }
Next: [object Object]
{ thing: 'table',
  name: 'setty',
  owner: 'bryan',
  'loc\r': 'new oak' }
Next: [object Object]
Completed
```